# Conway polyhedra notation calculator?

Tags: notation, polyhedra, online-resources

I recently read about Conway polyhedra notation, and I want to experiment with it. Are there any programs that take the notation, and output a representation of the shape?

Comment: [polyHédronisme](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/)

Comment: @achillehui, wow better than the one I posted, not a fan of the projection it uses, but it actually works for me. If you expand it into a answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment expand into answer per request.

In addition to the [original cnp calculator](http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/conway_notation.html) by George Hart, there is another calculator
[polyHédronisme](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/) by Anselm Levskaya.
The source of the later is available on [github](https://github.com/levskaya/polyhedronisme).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it yet but http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/conway_notation.html?notation=sA4 might work.

**EDIT:**
It does work just need to download a special viewer.